# is $ W = \{M = \begin{pmatrix}M_{11}&M_{12}\\M_{21}&M_{22}\end{pmatrix}\in \text{Mat}_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R}):\text{det}(M)=1\}$ A Vector Space?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am unsure whether: $$ W = \{M = \begin{pmatrix}M_{11}&M_{12}\\M_{21}&M_{22}\end{pmatrix}\in \text{Mat}_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R}):\text{det}(M)=1\}.$$ is a vector space, how should I go about working this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No, the zero matrix is not in the set. So it is not a vector space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because there is no zero element in the set.

However, it is a group! (under matrix multiplication). Here are the properties that make it a group:

For $A,B \in W$,

1. $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) = 1(1) = 1.$
2. Matrix multiplication is associative.
3. $\det{I} = 1$.
4. $\det{A^{-1}} = \frac{1}{\det{A}} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.$